# Swagger ui dose not work when @RequestParam annotation dose not set to method parameter

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have method in spring mvc controller .method parameter do not need to  set @RequestParam  and work correctly .I want use swagger and spring fox for api doc .but when do not set @RequestParam it parameter swagger  dose not work .I have 100 controller in my project  and can not set this annotation for all methods in controller . how can i solve this problem without add @RequestParam annotation ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public QueryResult<ActionViewModel> list(
            @RequestParam String searchFilter,
            @RequestParam String order, 
            @RequestParam int pageNumber/* swagger ok*/,
            int pageSize /* swagger problem*/) {
    // body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you swagger config, on the docket

```
enableUrlTemplating(false)
```

Decides whether to use URL templating for paths. This is especially useful when you have search APIs that might have multiple request mappings for each search use case.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/909